# Depend on local C# project

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget, class-library, dotnet-cli

I have two C# projects in the same directory.

```
.
├── MyLib
│   ├── MyLib.cs
│   ├── MyLib.csproj
│   └── bin
│       └── Debug
│           └── netstandard2.0
│               ├── MyLib.deps.json
│               ├── MyLib.dll
│               └── MyLib.pdb
└── MyApp
    ├── Program.cs
    ├── MyApp.csproj
    └── bin
        └── Debug
            └── netcoreapp2.2
                ├── MyApp.deps.json
                ├── MyApp.dll
                ├── MyApp.pdb
                ├── MyApp.runtimeconfig.dev.json
                └── MyApp.runtimeconfig.json
```

I would like `MyApp` to be able to access the classes etc. defined in `MyLib`.

How do I do that?

I have tried from `MyApp`

```
dotnet add package ../MyLib/MyLib.csproj
dotnet add package MyLib --source ../MyLib/bin/Debug
```

after `dotnet pack` from `MyLib`.

None work because the package cannot be found in the source `nuget.org`.

What's the easiest way for me to simply depend on my local project?

Comment: You should add a project reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference

Comment: Or you could just right click the project and add project reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly there. Projects are added by `reference` -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference

Try `dotnet add reference ../MyLib/MyLib.csproj`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [dotnet add reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference)

```
dotnet add [<PROJECT>] reference [-f|--framework <FRAMEWORK>]
     [--interactive] <PROJECT_REFERENCES>

dotnet add reference -h|--help
```